# How to create folder with specific path using grapgh API in sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to create a folder inside of a folder. I know how to create a folder using the php graph SDK, but it only create a folder in the root. What I want is to create a folder inside of another folder, assume that the path is existed.

Code to create a folder

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);
$graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/drive/root/children")
->attachBody(array(
    "name"=>"Test Folder",
    "folder"=>new stdClass(),
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"=>"rename"
))->execute();

return $graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the folder by specifying the path. Use `PATCH` instead of `POST`

```
PATCH /me/drive/root:/path/to/the/folder

{
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail"
}
```

PHP code:

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);
$graph->createRequest("PATCH", "/me/drive/root:/folder1/folder2/Test Folder")
->attachBody(array(
    "folder"=>new stdClass(),
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"=>"rename"
))->execute();

return $graph;
```

Comment: Thank you good sir for responding, I will test it later. I will update you if it works.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?